# Minimizing the chat window

Tags: javascript

**Here i have code for closing the window.**

```
    var textClose = document.createElement("span");
    textClose.setAttribute("class", "windowClose");
    textClose.innerHTML = "[X]";
    this.addOnClickListener(textClose, this.hide, this);
```

**here i am writing code for minimize but not working.**

```
    var textMin = document.createElement("span");
    textMin.setAttribute("class", "windowMin");
    textMin.innerHTML = "[-]";
    this.addOnClickListener(textMin, this.slideToggle, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var textClose = document.createElement("SPAN");
    var t = document.createTextNode("[X]");
    textClose.className = "windowClose"
    textClose.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(textClose);
    textClose.addEventListener("click",  function openWin() {
    window.close ();
    
});
  var textMin = document.createElement("SPAN");
var t1 = document.createTextNode("[-]");
    textMin.className = "windowMin";
    textMin.appendChild(t1);
    document.body.appendChild(textMin);
    textMin.addEventListener("click",  function minWin() {
    /*window.resizeTo(0,0);
//window.moveTo(0,screen.height-50);*/
//Close window Working in IE
//OR
window.resizeTo(250, 250);
window.focus();
});
```

```css
.windowClose{
color:#FF0000;
cursor:pointer
}
.windowMin{
color:#00FF00;
cursor:pointer
}
```